# How can the block size of a file store be portably obtained in Java 7?

Tags: java, file, filesystems, block, disk

I've looked at `java.nio.file.attribute.Attributes` and `java.nio.file.FileStore`, but couldn't find a way to discover the block-size of a disk-file.

Comment: Isn't block size intrinsically non-portable?  What if the file store doesn't use blocks (sure unlikely, but possible)?

Comment: @Mark The vast majority of file-stores are implemented via spinning disks and, consequently, use blocks. I can handle the case where the block size is one byte. What I want is a portable way to determine that size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/geekomatic/2009/12/29/1262124900000.html) on buffer size vs I/O throughput. Synopsis: nio handles all of that for you. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream) concludes you should use a power of 2.

Comment: Devon, I want a way to determine the block size programmatically that doesn't rely on conducting an experiment and interpreting the results.

Comment: I understand that. However, there is no mechanism in Java that exposes the fielsystem's preferred IO size. Given that, the best fall back position is to use a likely multiple and trust the io/nio subsystem to do the right thing. Generally speaking, filesystems use I/O sizes of 4K, 8K, or 16K. So, using one of those sizes will generally be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 does not have the requested information, and the users question is related to Java 7.

But in Java 10, there was a new method introduced which provides the requested information.

The [getBlockSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#getBlockSize()) method of a FileStore class is used to return the number of bytes per block in this file store Object. Every File storage is organized into discrete sequences of bytes called blocks and a block is the smallest storage unit of a file store. Every read and write operation is performed on multiple blocks. This method is helpful in getting the size of Block.