# Java: How to create SHA-1 for a file?

Tags: java, cryptography, sha

What is the best way to create a SHA-1 for a very large file in pure Java6? How to implement this method:

```
public abstract String createSha1(java.io.File file);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the `MessageDigest` class and supply data piece by piece.  The example below ignores details like turning byte[] into string and closing the file, but should give you the general idea.

```
public byte[] createSha1(File file) throws Exception  {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    int n = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while (n != -1) {
        n = fis.read(buffer);
        if (n > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
    return digest.digest();
}
```

Comment: The DigestInputStream class is even easier to use. Actually maybe not, but it is good to try it as an alternative and compare to this.

Comment: Use BufferedInputStream instead of creating your own buffer:

`InputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));`

Comment: @Jeff Foster how you determined that the size of `byte[] buffer` is `8192`?

Comment: @ThunderWiring Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream

Comment: The FIleInputStream should be closed, as in the other response

Answer (score 24):

Op requested the function to return a String of the SHA1, so I took @jeffs answer and added the missing conversion to String:

```
/**
 * Read the file and calculate the SHA-1 checksum
 * 
 * @param file
 *            the file to read
 * @return the hex representation of the SHA-1 using uppercase chars
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 *             if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a
 *             regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for
 *             reading
 * @throws IOException
 *             if an I/O error occurs
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 *             should never happen
 */
private static String calcSHA1(File file) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len = input.read(buffer);

        while (len != -1) {
            sha1.update(buffer, 0, len);
            len = input.read(buffer);
        }

        return new HexBinaryAdapter().marshal(sha1.digest());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String computeFileSHA1( File file ) throws IOException
{
    String sha1 = null;
    MessageDigest digest;
    try
    {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
    }
    catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e1 )
    {
        throw new IOException( "Impossible to get SHA-1 digester", e1 );
    }
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream( file );
         DigestInputStream digestStream = new DigestInputStream( input, digest ) )
    {
        while(digestStream.read() != -1){
            // read file stream without buffer
        }
        MessageDigest msgDigest = digestStream.getMessageDigest();
        sha1 = new HexBinaryAdapter().marshal( msgDigest.digest() );
    }
    return sha1;
}
```

Comment: Although your answer may be correct, it would be helpful to the OP if you could add some commentary explaining why it is. This way it will be useful to others.

Comment: Initially request was related to Java6. Your code provided will not been compiled under Java6!