# Android get the real path and file name from Uri

Tags: android, hash

```
public void fileSearching(){
    try{
        // find1, find2 are buttons that open the file explorer
        find1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("file/*");
                check = 0;
                startActivityForResult(i, CODE);
            }
        });
        find2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("file/*");
                check = 1;
                startActivityForResult(i, CODE);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data){
    if (request == CODE && result == RESULT_OK){
        Uri u = data.getData();
        String path = data.getData().getPath();
    }
}
```

Retrurns **/external/file/59** but i need **/sdcard/downloads/...**  + file name
I need this because i want to get a sha-1,md5,... hash for any file.
If i use the  "/external/file/xx" it gives me a FileNotFoundException.
I've tried some solutions that were already presented but none seemed to work for me or i didn't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

> Retrurns /external/file/59

That is because you did not look at the scheme of the `Uri`. `getPath()` **only** has meaning if the scheme is `file`. You will rarely get a `Uri` with a `file` scheme. Usually, it will have a `content` scheme, in which case the path is meaningless to you.

> I need this because i want to get a sha-1,md5,... hash for any file.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Pass that `InputStream` to [your hashing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293816/115145).