# MultipartFile issue, unable to convert to File

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to to upload above 1 GB file, I am using Spring Boot.

I've tried with below code, but I am getting as Out of Memory error.

```
public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        try {       
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

            SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

            String uploadFile= restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(convert(file)), headers), String.class).getBody();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception Occured", e);
        }
    }


    private static File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;    
    }
```

The Main problem I am facing is, I am  unable to convert MultipartFile to java.io.File.

I've even tried replacing `FileSystemResource` with `ByteArrayResource`, but still getting OOM error.

I've even tried using below code too:

```
private static File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        CommonsMultipartFile commonsMultipartFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) multipartFile;
        FileItem fileItem = commonsMultipartFile.getFileItem();
        DiskFileItem diskFileItem = (DiskFileItem) fileItem;
        String absPath = diskFileItem.getStoreLocation().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(absPath);  
    }
```

But I am getting below exception for above snippet:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot
>   be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

1. Could anyone please tell me on how to convert MultipartFile to java.io.File?
2. And also is there any other approach better than `FileSystemResource` bcoz I will have to create new file in server everytime before uploading. If file is more than 1GB, another 1 GB new file has to be created on server side, and has to manually delete that file again, which I personally didn't like this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getBytes()` tries to load the whole byte array into memory which is causing your `OOM` what you need to do is stream the file and write it out.

Try the following:

```
private static Path convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
  Path newFile = Paths.get(file.getOriginalFilename());
  try(InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
     OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(newFile))) {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int read = 0;
     while((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       os.write(buffer,0,read);
     }
  }
  return newFile;  
}
```

I changed your method to return a `Path` instead of `File` which is part of the `java.nio` package. The package is preferred over `java.io` as its been optimized more.

If you do need a `File` object you can call `newFile.toFile()`

Since it returns a `Path` object you can use the `java.nio.file.Files` class to relocate the file to your preferred directory once it has been written out

```
private static void relocateFile(Path original, Path newLoc) throws IOException {
  if(Files.isDirectory(newLoc)) {
    newLoc = newLoc.resolve(original.getFileName());
  }
  Files.move(original, newLoc);
}
```

Comment: Note you could also use `Files.copy(is, newFile)` or, if using Java 9+, `is.transferTo(os)`. You do lose control over the buffer size, however.

Comment: Those are good suggestions too. I'm not sure how `Files.copy` works under the hood (haven't looked at the source) but I tend to like controlling the buffer size especially on a machine that may have limited resources

Comment: @locus2k one doubt: why this code still getting OOM, I mean:

 try(InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int read = 0;
     while((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer,0,read);
      }

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream is still storing the bytes in memory as you're not writing it to file as you read thus the `OOM`

Comment: @locus2k okay, got it. thnq

Comment: @locus2k 2 questions: In your code, can I use BufferedInputStream and write it to file 4kb each time? and currently we have kepted size as 4096, how do you decide this size? why cannot I use more bytesize to read?

Comment: For what you're doing you do not have to wrap it into a `BufferedInputStream` unless you want to take advantage of some of the higher level options. You can increase your buffer size as you see fit. I just use `4096` for the example. You can play with it to see what is optimal for your solution

Comment: @locus2k sorry, I ddin't get , whats the problem wrapping with BufferedInputStream  ?

Comment: There is no issue wrapping it around a `BufferedInputStream` but it is unnecessary for the function as it will provide no significant improvements.

Comment: @locus2k Reading from buffer is much better than InputStream, right? I mean in case of InputStream, OS has to involve to read bytes, in case of BufferedInputStream , we read from buffer(ie., memory), right?

Comment: No, `InputStream` is just an abstraction. `BufferedInputStream` implements `InputStream` under the hood and then adds some more functionality that you can take advantage of. Both read a section of information and stores it into memory. Take a look at this answer for a better explanation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964044/should-i-always-wrap-an-inputstream-as-bufferedinputstream

Comment: @locus2k okay, thanks for the link. one last thing: I've actually tried using different buffer sizes (4096 which is 4KB, 1048576 which is 1MB), but I found that 4Kb took less time than 1MB (I've tested with 1.2GB file), any idea?

Comment: @john See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143501/java-io-performance-issue and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream