# Is there a disadvantage to large buffers?

Tags: java, android, networking, io, buffer

In experimenting with transferring files over networks in Java, I've found that buffers > 64k give best performance. However from what I've seen googling around (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237495/1492861)), most people recommend smaller buffers of 8-32k because it can fit in the CPU cache. Is that factor important when transferring large volumes of data? Would it be better to sacrifice better network throughput and go with the smaller buffer? (this includes Android devices too, perhaps any low power device)

Comment: I think you should continue your experiments, including some low power Android devices. Only measurement can tell which consideration is more important in your situation.

Comment: Cache locality isn't going to make any difference at network rates. Basically the bigger the better except in memory limited situations like mobile devices.

Comment: Well I've found that on my Galaxy S2, allocating a 256k byte `ByteBuffer` once and using it to retrieve data in a loop caused the Garbage Collector to run continuously - not good. That said, when writing to the internal storage of the phone usually tops out at 4-5 MB/sec regardless of buffer size, so 64-128k is usually good. On the desktop hardware spectrum I managed to saturate a Gigabit network connection using a 256k buffer and an SSD.