# Out of memory, an in-memory stream

Tags: android

When I use a very large file, the error happens out of memory, no way to treat this problem, or why not be happening in the code below?

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //10*1024 = 10KB
    byte[] byteBuffer   = new byte[20*2048]; 

    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while ((i = is.read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length)) > 0) {

        baos.write(byteBuffer, 0, i);

    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: refer to [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream). That buffer size is not about your file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByteArrayOutputStream definition "A specialized OutputStream for class for writing content to an (internal) byte array. **As bytes are written to this stream, the byte array may be expanded to hold more bytes**. When the writing is considered to be finished, a copy of the byte array can be requested from the class."

You are writing Integer.MAX_VALUE * 10240 bytes to memory.

You may want to change the title to "Out of memory when writing to an in-memory stream"

Comment: a solution : android:largeHeap="true" , but  Your tip will be used