# Can't run two threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm having trouble running these two threads in Java. I have two methods in the client class and in each method they both have a socket of different ports but when I run the client, i see the error for a split second of one of the threads but the other one that sends the file over works.

Any help?

ClientApp.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    Thread getFileThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Client client = new Client();

            try {
                client.getTheFile("girlwithmask.jpg");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    Thread getListOfFilesThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Client client = new Client();

            ArrayList<String> listOfFiles = null;
            try {
                listOfFiles = client.getFileList();
                System.out.println(listOfFiles.get(1));
                notify();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    getListOfFilesThread.start();
    getFileThread.start();
}
```

Client.java

```
    public class Client {
        private static final int PORT = 2665;
        private static String HOST = "localhost";

        Client() {

        }

        public void getTheFile(String filename) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            filename = "girlwithmask.jpg";  ///this is temporary

            int filesize = 5000000;   //buffer size 5mb
            int bytesRead;
            int currentTotalNumberOfBytes = 0;

            //connect to port on server - server waits for this after running socket.accept() in the Server class
            Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[filesize];   //create a byte array of 5mb
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  //channel to to server
            FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream("myClientFiles/" + filename);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutStream);

            bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            currentTotalNumberOfBytes = bytesRead;

            do { //read till the end and store total in bytesRead and add it to currentTotalNumberOfBytes
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, currentTotalNumberOfBytes, (byteArray.length - currentTotalNumberOfBytes));
                if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                    currentTotalNumberOfBytes += bytesRead;
                }
            } while (bytesRead > -1); // when bytesRead == -1, there's no more data left and we exit the loop

            bufferOutStream.write(byteArray, 0, currentTotalNumberOfBytes); //write the bytes to the file

            bufferOutStream.flush();
            bufferOutStream.close();
            socket.close();

        }

        public ArrayList<String> getFileList() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
            ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

            ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            Object object = objectInput.readObject();
            titleList = (ArrayList<String>) object;
            // System.out.println(titleList.get(2));

            return titleList;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what is going on here. Been working with this for a couple of hours.

Comment: I see "the error". What is "the error"?

Comment: oh, that's a mistake, ignore that comment

Comment: No, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Can you format your code so its readable?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of an actual error, or indeed question, all we can do is critique your code:

```
 byte[] byteArray = new byte[filesize];   //create a byte array of 5mb
```

You don't *know* what `filesize` is. You've hardcoded a ***guess*** of 5000000. This will not work for any case where the filesize is bigger than 5000000 which might be very often. There is an approach where you don't *need* to know the filesize: *nor* do you need a buffer the size of the whole file in the first place. You're assuming the file fits into memory and that the file length fits into an `int.` Both assumptions may be wrong. Use a smaller buffer size of 8192 or some such reasonable number which is usually a multiple of 1024 to get a good memory alignment. Hard-coding a big size of 5000000 has the drawbacks mentioned.

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  //channel to to server
FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream("myClientFiles/" + filename);
BufferedOutputStream bufferOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutStream);
```

You don't really need the `BufferedOutputStream` with this code, or at least with this code as it's going to be, but let it pass for now.

```
bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
currentTotalNumberOfBytes = bytesRead;
do { //read till the end and store total in bytesRead and add it to currentTotalNumberOfBytes
    bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, currentTotalNumberOfBytes, (byteArray.length - currentTotalNumberOfBytes));
    if (bytesRead >= 0) {
        currentTotalNumberOfBytes += bytesRead;
    }
} while (bytesRead > -1); // when bytesRead == -1, there's no more data left and we exit the loop
bufferOutStream.write(byteArray, 0, currentTotalNumberOfBytes); //write the bytes to the file
```

To make this code shorter you might want to change it to the canonical form:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

substituting variable names as appropriate. You will:

1. Save memory
2. Reduce latency
3. Have clear well-tested code that's been working for 18 years.

   ```
   bufferOutStream.flush();
   ```

`flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

```
    bufferOutStream.close();
    socket.close();
```

Closing the socket after closing its output stream (or input stream) is redundant. Just close the output stream. In a `finally` block.

Comment: what is the 8192 comment about? I didn't understand it

Comment: @WolfgangFahl; reading a buffer of five million bytes is, uh, unusual.  Reading a buffer of somewhere between 1k and 8k bytes at a time is normal/expected.  8k is 8192, 2 ^ 13, and is a pretty typical buffer size to use here.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl or see this SO article on filesystem block sizes, which is what you're normally trying to match up with there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream