# Would there be an advantage to copying data from managed stream to an intptr in blocks of 4096?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, libsndfile

In my libsndfile wrapper currently im using this.
To read my stream (Must be a stream im loading from resource)
But is this the best way i can fill the pointer with the requested data?

```
public static void ReadStream(Stream input,IntPtr output,int size)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
    int i = BufferSize;
    int ptr_offset = 0;

    while (i == BufferSize || ptr_offset==size)
    {
        i = input.Read(data, 0, BufferSize);

        if (i + ptr_offset > size)
            i = size - ptr_offset;

        MarshalExt.Copy_MU(data, 0, output, ptr_offset, (uint)i);
        ptr_offset += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this question is about Java, I believe its answer applies here and will be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream

Comment: @Amy i see. would this still apply in memory to memory transfers? Mainly doing this so i dont have 3 buffers the size of 44100*4 floating around.

Comment: It is a bit clumsy, but that is unavoidable when you only have a Stream to read from.  It just doesn't matter, latency is very low and this is many orders of magnitude faster than you'd ever need to keep libsndfile happy.

Comment: @HansPassant So it should be fast and will keep my need of not using two massive buffers.